# How to connect to host machine from within Virtual PC image

Tags: networking, virtual-pc

I am putting together a SVN demonstration using a WinXP Virtual PC image, and am unable to see my host machine from within the VPC guest OS.

This demo will be performed while disconnected from our LAN, so I installed the Microsoft Loopback adapter on my laptop.  In the TCP/IP settings I manually set the IP address to 192.168.3.1 to avoid conflicts with our internal network.  In the VPC image settings I set the Network Type to Microsoft Loopback Adapter and set the IP address to 192.168.3.2.

I cannot ping my host machine from the guest OS and vice versa.  I've followed through several different how-to pages on this subject but still cannot determine why this isn't working.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

It might just be because by default Windows XP Firewall blocks ping requests.

To enable pings do the following:

1. Open *Windows Firewall* in the *Control Panel*
2. On the *General* tab check Windows Firewall is On.  If it's Off you're probably using another firewall and will need to configure that.
3. On the *Advanced* tab click the Settings button under *ICMP*.
4. Tick the box next to *Allow incoming echo request*.
5. Click *OK* on the ICMP dialog.
6. Click *OK* on the Wndows Firewall dialog.

Comment: Instructions for Win7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc972926(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

So your host machine's loopback is set to 192.168.3.1 (subnet 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.3.1) and your VM's network adapter is set to 192.168.3.2 (subnet 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.3.1)?  They should be able to see each other, there's not much else to this setup.

I'd shake things up:

- Install the VM additions, maybe the network driver that comes with the guest OS isn't cutting it.
- Try a different subnet, maybe 192.168.22.1.
- Disable your host machine's other network adapters for a bit, maybe packets are getting routed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that firewalls are off the only reason not able to ping Microsoft loop back adapter is some antivirus software is obsolete so make It updated or else just remove it from add/remove programs then go to control panel and select firewall just make sure firewall should be in off then only we can ping from virtual pc to host Microsoft loopback adapter.....just check it out